# Can an anonymous class in Java have other methods than his superclass?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods, overriding

I know that anonymous classes are good for overriding and so on but I wonder if you can also add other methods that doesn't exist in the parent class like in the example below.

This is my class with wieBenIk as only method.

```
public class Driehoek {

//methoden
public void wieBenIk(){
    System.out.println("ik ben een driehoek");
}
```

}

and here is my anonymous class where I added newMethod.

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Driehoek test = new Driehoek(){

        @Override
        public void wieBenIk() {
            System.out.println("overrided by anonymous class");
        }

        public void newMethod(){
            System.out.println("I am a new method");
        }
    };

    test.newMethod();

}
```

}

My question is why is test.newMethod() not working? Isn't it a child class like another?
Thanks everyone for helping me.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Methods execute when called, it won't run just because it exists.  And it has to be noted that there's no easy way to call such a method.

Comment: I mean why is test.newMethod() not executing? What do you mean by "it won't run because it exists"? What does exist?

Comment: You wrote code, therefore it exists.  That existence is not sufficient for the code to execute. You have to write a call to that method into somewhere (that is already itself executed).

Comment: But I seem to have misread your code previously. You have coded a call.  The problem is not that it's not executing, it's surely that **it won't compile**.  It won't compile because the class Driehoek does not have a method named newMethod.

Comment: Ok thank you. Can you tell me how you know all this and where you learned it? I am learning from w3school and they never talk about anonymous classes. I had to discover it by myself.and there is so little information about that on the internet

Comment: As a lifelong programmer, it seems self-evident to me (and not specific to Java). So I cant tell you how I know it. I can't remember ever being unable to read, either :-)  But my last piece of old-fogey advice is to find a good Java book (on paper) and read it.

Comment: By self-evident, I refer to the fact that all that is known from the declaration Driehoek test is that test is a Driehoek, and therefore you can only assume the properties of a Driehoek. If I talk only about a "cat", then you can't assume it's a leopard, even though it may actually be one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*test* is declared as an instance of *Driehoek*. As such, for the compiler it will have the members of *Driehoek*.

Similarly, if you define

```
Object test = new Driehoek() {....};
```

for the compiler *test* will only have available the *Object* members.

If you add more members to the anonymous class, the compiler will not know that *test* has those methods available. So it does not allow you to use them

Comment: Thanks SJuan76. Now I understand it better. So do you agree that the only thing you can do with anonymous classes is to override methods of the parent class?

Comment: That's not the way I'd express it.  For example, your wieBenIk method could call newMethod quite happily.  The limitation is, rather, that the accessible capabilities of the object are those of the superclass. In situations of any complexity, defining auxiliary methods provides useful structure.

Comment: Ok thanks bro. Can you tell me how you know all this and where you learned it? I am learning from w3school and they never talk about anonymous classes. I had to discover it by myself.and there is so little information about that on the internet.